# Remove duplicates in array of Either with fp-ts

Tags: javascript, typescript, functional-programming, fp-ts

What's the best way to remove duplicates of an array of Either in Functional Programming using `fp-ts`?

This is my attemp:

```
import { either as E, pipeable as P } from "fp-ts";
import { flow } from "fp-ts/lib/function";

interface IItem {
  type: "VALID" | "INVALID";
  value: string;
}

// Building some fake data
const buildItem = (value?: string): E.Either<unknown, string> =>
  value != null ? E.right(value) : E.left({ type: "INVALID", value: "" });

// We will always have an array of Either
const items = [
  buildItem("aa"),
  buildItem("ab"),
  buildItem(),
  buildItem("ac"),
  buildItem("ab"),
  buildItem("ac"),
  buildItem(),
  buildItem("aa")
];

const checkList: string[] = [];
export const program = flow(
  () => items,
  x =>
    x.reduce(
      (acc, item) =>
        P.pipe(
          item,
          E.chain(value => {
            if (checkList.indexOf(value) < 0) {
              checkList.push(value);
              return E.right({ type: "VALID", value: value } as IItem);
            }
            return E.left({ type: "INVALID", value: value } as IItem);
          }),
          v => acc.concat(v)
        ),
      [] as E.Either<unknown, IItem>[]
    )
);
```

[Playground link](https://codesandbox.io/s/reduce-array-in-fp-ts-vtys9)

Comment: What about using `.filter()` to get rid of duplicates and `.map()` over the rest to return a new formed list?

Comment: I'm expecting to use some sort of Either or Option here. I guess I have to update the question with those.

Comment: Ah okay, got it! I can give you a basic place to start in pure JS if it works?

Comment: Sure @weirdpanda go ahead. I will try to update the question for better visibility and clarification.

Comment: @AminPaks, it's not entirely clear how the code snippets above relate to the question you asked. I think things my be clearer if you remove the code and ask the question using only types rather than implementations. It seems like `uniq(eqString)(items.filter(notNull))` is all you really need, but your question asks about reduce. Reduce doesn't seem necessary for what you're doing.

Comment: @DerrickBeining would you write your answer in a valid code? Remember we have an array of `Either` or `Option`, that's required from my implementation

Comment: @AminPaks I'm saying using reduce and Either doesn't seem necessary given the code snippet you posted.

Comment: @AminPaks It looks like all you're trying to do is remove `null`s and duplicates from `items`. You don't need reduce or Either for that: https://codesandbox.io/s/reduce-array-in-fp-ts-ohlb4?file=/src/index.ts

Comment: @DerrickBeining well as I already said the requirement of the question is that the input is an array of `Either` or `Option`. I didn't build the question properly I guess. Let me update the question

Comment: @AminPaks the input to what? Try re-phrasing the question like this: "Using `fp-ts`, how can I implement a function that takes a `Foo` and returns a `Bar` and fulfills the following requirements: 1) ... 2) ...

Comment: @DerrickBeining Is this not yet clear enough "Remove duplications of an array of Either or Option"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212439/discussion-between-derrick-beining-and-amin-paks).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, in `fp-ts`, you can remove duplicates from an `Array<A>` by using `uniq` from `fp-ts/lib/Array`. Given an `Eq<A>` and an `Array<A>` it will return an `Array<A>` where all `A`s are unique.

In your case, it appears you want de-duplicate an `Array<Either<IItem, IItem>>`. That means, in order to use `uniq`, you are going to need an instance of `Eq<Either<IItem, IItem>>`. The way you get that is to use `getEq` from `fp-ts/lib/Either`. It requires you to provide an `Eq` instance for each type your `Either` is parameterized by, one for the left case and another for the right case. So for `Either<E, R>`, `getEq` will take an `Eq<E>` and an `Eq<R>` and give you an `Eq<Either<E, R>>`. In your situation, `E` and `R` are the same (i.e. `IItem`), so you just use the same `Eq<IItem>` instance twice.

Most likely, the instance of `Eq<IItem>` you want will look like this:

```
// IItem.ts |
//-----------
import { Eq, contramap, getStructEq, eqString } from 'fp-ts/lib/Eq'

export interface IItem {
  type: "VALID" | "INVALID";
  value: string;
}

export const eqIItem: Eq<IItem> = getStructEq({
  type: contramap((t: "VALID" | "INVALID"): string => t)(eqString),
  value: eqString
})
```

Once you have that, you can then deduplicate your `Array<Either<IItem, IItem>>` with `uniq` like this:

```
// elsewhere.ts |
//---------------
import { array, either } from 'fp-ts'
import { Either } from 'fp-ts/lib/Either'
import { IItem, eqIItem } from './IItem.ts'

const items: Array<Either<IItem, IItem>> = []

const uniqItems = uniq(either.getEq(eqIItem, eqIItem))(items)
```

The `uniqItems` constant will then be an `Array<Either<IItem, IItem>>` where no two `Either<IItem, IItem>` are "equal" as defined by `Eq<Either<IItem, IItem>>`.

Comment: It appreards there is no getStruct in fp-ts v2 https://gcanti.github.io/fp-ts/modules/Eq.ts.html

Comment: I think I understood the usage of getEq and mixing it with eqString. The only thing is do I need to use eqStruct if yes where I should import it from?

Comment: @AminPaks, sorry. It was a typo. Fixed.